# Spring Cloud Data Flow CF bind services to task/app

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm using SCDF CF  server with manifest to bind services to tasks and stream apps, my question is how can I bind *particular* service to *specific* task/stream app, so far I have

`SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_STREAM_SERVICES: serviceName1
SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_TASK_SERVICES: serviceName2`

which binds `serviceName1` and `serviceName2` to **each** stream/task app

Please advise

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind a particular service to individual apps, you can use the deployment properties while deploying the stream.

You'd use the `deployer.<APP_NAME>.cloudfoundry.services` pattern to pin a particular service binding.

Here's the [write-up](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-service-binding-at-application-level) that you may find it useful.

Comment: Thanks @sabby-anandan, I overlooked this,  sorry to bother you with documented features...